# How to vertically align on an image overlay card in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, overlay, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to center a FontAwesome icon in the center of an Image Overlay Card and I'm being unable to center it vertically.

I've tried multiple other suggestions such as using `d-flex` and `justify-content-center` but none seem to work. What am I missing?

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="card bg-dark text-white">
      <img class="card-img" src="http://placehold.jp/500x200.png" alt="Example">
      <div class="card-img-overlay text-center">
          <i class="fab fa-youtube fa-5x" style="color:#FF0000"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want the icon to be centered in the middle of the image, but can only align it horizontally and not vertically. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add `d-flex` class to your `.card-img-overlay` element, then add `class="align-self-center mx-auto"` to the inner `a` element:

```
<div class="card bg-dark text-white">
   <img class="card-img" src="images/example.jpg" alt="Example">
   <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex">
     <a class="align-self-center mx-auto" data-fancybox href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ">
       <i class="fa fa-youtube fa-5x zoom" style="color:#FF0000"></i>
     </a>  
   </div>
</div>
```

More info about `align-self-center` on official BS4 doc: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#align-self

Comment: This has fixed my issue. I was adding the `align-self-center mx-auto` class to the `i class=""` of the icon instead of the `a=class""` of the actual link. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use bootstrap [flex utilities class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/) on card-img-overlay element :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card bg-dark text-white">
   <img class="card-img" src="https://fakeimg.pl/250x100/000000/" alt="Example">
   <div class="card-img-overlay text-center d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
      <a data-fancybox href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" class="">
      <i class="fab fa-youtube fa-5x zoom" style="color:#FF0000"></i>
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt was correct (Adding `d-flex` and `justify-content-center` class). You just forgot to also add `align-items-center` class.